# Regular expression on negate of 4 digits appended with a hyphen without using negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have tried with many possible solutions of regex to identify lines that do not start with 4 digits and a hyphen without using negative lookahead. The regex I am trying to configure in filebeat to identify lines that do not start with year and a hyphen. An example can be `2023-`.

One regex with negative lookahead which works is as `^((?!(^[0-9]{4}-$)).)*$` which can be used as a start to identify the problem. Any help regarding this that could be done without the negative lookahead.?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Couldn't you just match lines that *do* start with this, and then negate the test to filter them out of the results?

Comment: BTW, the negative lookahead shouldn't have `$` in it.

Comment: @Barmar I understood regarding to filter out. I'm in a situation on directly applying the regex that adding additional logic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:.{0,3}(?:[^\d\n]|$)|\d{4}(?:[^-\n]|$)).*
```

The first alternative matches a string where one of the first 4 characters isn't a digit. The second alternative matches 4 digits not followed by a hyphen.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/HK7HaR/5)

Comment: That does not allow `3`, `33`, and `333`.